# MySQL - Network time

Tags: mysql

I read a couple of posts online regarding this issue but seems like no one really knows the answer.

When running a query I see
`1 query 0.5 sec + 30 secs network`

This is ridiculous since the client and server are both on the same machine and my select is `SELECT 1 FROM ... LIMIT 100000` , no there isnt alot of data sent from the server to the client;

So what the hell is this `secs network`.

Comment: What client are you using to execute the query?

Comment: HeidiSQL client

Comment: How many rows does it show at once? If it is only 1000 until you scroll down, that might be from when the query finished to when you scrolled to the bottom of the results.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether HeidiSQL grabs the entire resultset all at once?  Or gets it piecemeal?

Comment: Looks like the entire set, but it also happen to me with `select count(*)`

Comment: Its been 5 years, and don't have a concrete answer for this. Is it happening because of cloud infrastructures? I was working with some of the SPs for the performance tuning and observed the query execution times are less than 1 sec (0.2 or 0.3), but the network time is almost 3.5 secs. And, it's not only happening with Heidi, even observed the same in other clients as well like sqlyog, but their verbiage for network time is different.

Answer (score 0):

@omri @Gowtham Vakani
Seems the index not working cause this problem,at least mine is.

Run "explain select * ... " to find out index working or not.
If you are using windows 10 or later, monitoring you hdd/ssd read.

I created index from gui, but it doesn't work.
Every sql search will read whole database file.

After recreate index by sql statement,explain shows index works,and task manager shows less read data than before.

Most of the network time waste on I/O.